# Android animated transition

Tags: android, animation, transition

How to make circular animated transition from top left to right bottom not as traditional way, I tried

```
<translate
    android:duration ="1200"
    android:fromYDelta="-1000"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Android transition API. If you're supporting Lollipop+ (ArcMotion was added in Lollipop while transition API is available from KitKat) you might use native transitions, otherwise you might want to use Transitions-Everywhere library. I think this does what you want to do: https://github.com/andkulikov/Transitions-Everywhere/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/andkulikov/transitionseverywhere/PathMotionSample.java